# textbox lines into listview subitems vb.net

Tags: vb.net, listview, textbox, lines

i have an app that detect wifi networks
i have a listviewitems with wifi ssid , signal and security and i have 
a richtextbox that each line contains mac address of each ssid that is ordred
i want to add each line to each item as subitem
i used this code but number of items are changeable

```
LVW.Items(0).SubItems(3).Text = RichTextBox1.Lines(0) 
LVW.Items(1).SubItems(3).Text = RichTextBox1.Lines(1)
LVW.Items(2).SubItems(3).Text = RichTextBox1.Lines(2)     
LVW.Items(4).SubItems(3).Text = RichTextBox1.Lines(4)
LVW.Items(5).SubItems(3).Text = RichTextBox1.Lines(5)
LVW.Items(6).SubItems(3).Text = RichTextBox1.Lines(6)
LVW.Items(7).SubItems(3).Text = RichTextBox1.Lines(7)
LVW.Items(8).SubItems(3).Text = RichTextBox1.Lines(8)
LVW.Items(9).SubItems(3).Text = RichTextBox1.Lines(9)
LVW.Items(10).SubItems(3).Text = RichTextBox1.Lines(10)
LVW.Items(11).SubItems(3).Text = RichTextBox1.Lines(11)
LVW.Items(12).SubItems(3).Text = RichTextBox1.Lines(12)
LVW.Items(13).SubItems(3).Text = RichTextBox1.Lines(13)
LVW.Items(14).SubItems(3).Text = RichTextBox1.Lines(14)
LVW.Items(15).SubItems(3).Text = RichTextBox1.Lines(15)
```

here's the picture
   [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
If RichTextBox1.Lines.Count > 0 And LVW.Items.Count = RichTextBox1.Lines.Count Then
    For i As Integer = 0 To RichTextBox1.Lines.Count - 1
        LVW.Items(i).SubItems(3).Text = RichTextBox1.Lines(i)
    Next
Else
    MsgBox("Invalid number of lines in RichTextBox1")
End If
```

Comment: Your code didn't work for me                                                                                but i tried try and catch ex as exception and it worked like a charm               thanks anyway for all :D